# Does my R code contain errors and does it answer the question?

Tags: r

So I am a literal beginner in R but we have been given a challenging task. I did what I could but I don't know how to check if code is correct. Can anyone help tell me if the code is correct and how to test-run my code?

This is my code:

```
colorgame = function(games){
  
  money = 0
  
  set.seed(100) # Pseudo-RNG, so we can generate results
  
  for(i in 1:games){
    
    diceRoll = sample(1:6,1) # Represents the 6 different colors
    
  if(diceRoll = 1) {# 1 represents the color the player always bets on
    
      money = money + 100
      
      }else {money = money - 80}
    
    
  } return(money/games)
}
```

And this is the question:

Three colored dice are being tossed and the player will bet money to one of the 6 colors. A player wins the same amount, twice the amount, or three times the amount of money he bet if the color he chose matches the colors from the 3 dice that has been rolled. Suppose that a player only bets one color for every round. Simulate this game and show that a player will eventually lose his money.

Comment: `if(diceRoll == 1) ...`

Comment: oh wow now theres no error when i run the code

Comment: is there a way to see if the player loses money? i dont know how to test that bit

Comment: `colorgame(1000)` Average lost: (1*100 - 5*80)/6 = -50

Comment: Note to beginner: Since R is a vectorized paradigm, `for` loops should only be used when absolutely necessary.  Here is a good compare and contrast of vectorization versus conventional looping methods: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2014/01/how-to-use-vectorization-to-streamline-simulations/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you writing R code without having R available to test it? You need to make three corrections to get it running:

- In the `if` statement, use `==` instead of `=` (`==` is a logical comparison, `=` is an assignment).
- In R, you have to use the next line after `}`. You have to change that before `else` and before `return`. But you could also leave those `{}` out in your case.

```
colorgame = function(games) {
  money = 0
  set.seed(100) # Pseudo-RNG, so we can generate results
  for(i in 1:games) {
    diceRoll = sample(1:6,1) # Represents the 6 different colors
    if(diceRoll == 1) money = money + 100 # 1 represents the color the player always bets on
    else money = money - 80
  }
  return(money/games)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Ive done it now but is there a way i will see how much money the player has after n games?? im fairly new in R, im trying to see when this player starts to lose money and i couldnt figure it out with youtube and stuff

Comment: `games <- 100;
out <- sample(rep(c(100, -80), c(1,5)), games, repl=TRUE);
cumsum(out)`